# How to edit or update the text inside the Text Field in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the .gif of this screen : http://g.recordit.co/73jHPP5LE6.gif

As you can see in the picture above there is an UILabel Rp `"25.000.000"` and a text inside the TextField `"25000000"` (after the user fill the text field). Both of them is actually a currency.

I want to edit the text inside the Textfield from `"25000000"` to `"25.000.000"`, I can give the dot (.) separator using a function, let say `formattedWithSeparator()` that can be used for an Int like this:

```
25000.formattedWithSeparator()
```

But I don't know where do I have to implement that function If I want to edit / update the text (not placeholder) inside the TextField live when the user update / write in the text field.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a method that is an `IBAction` for the control event `editingChanged`, right?

```
@IBAction func textChanged() {
    ...
}
```

In this method, you can change the text field's text:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
// set other properties of the formatter e.g. locale if you want

// remove the grouping separators (the dots) first, then convert to Int
if let amount = Int(tfAmount.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: formatter.groupingSeparator, with: "") ?? "") {
    if let formatted = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: amount)) {
        yourTextField.text = formatted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTextFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
}

func myTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if let amountString = textField.text?.currencyInputFormatting() {
        textField.text = amountString
    }
}

extension String {

    // formatting text for currency textField
    func currencyInputFormatting() -> String {

        var number: NSNumber!
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
        formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

        var amountWithPrefix = self

        // remove from String: "$", ".", ","
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)
        amountWithPrefix = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: amountWithPrefix, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: "")

        let double = (amountWithPrefix as NSString).doubleValue
        number = NSNumber(value: (double / 100))

        // if first number is 0 or all numbers were deleted
        guard number != 0 as NSNumber else {
            return ""
        }

        return formatter.string(from: number)!
    }
}
```